# Django Prefecth - call root elements field in filter

Tags: python, django

Here is my code, I am retrieving a Feed and all related data using the query. I am also checking if the user who is retrieving the feed is also a friend of the user who posted the feed. For friend relationships, I am using the ***Friends*** model. ***viewer_id*** and ***feed_id*** will be given by the system.

I want to replace ?????? with a field from ***Feed*** model (like *user_id* who posted the Feed)

```
  feed = Feed.objects.select_related(
                    'user_info', 'images'
                ).prefetch_related(
                    'tags',
                    Prefetch(
                        "friends_set",
                        queryset=Friends.objects.filter(user=viewer_id, follows=??????),
                        to_attr="friends"
                    ),
                ).get(id=feed_id)
```

Here is my UserInfo model

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, db_index=True)
    college = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, 
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is my Feed Model

```
  class Feed(models.Model):
        user_info = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        description = models.TextField()
        images = models.OneToOneField(ImageAlbum, related_name='model', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is my Friends model

```
class Friends(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, related_name="user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follows = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, related_name="follows", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Please include your Feed and Friends models.

Comment: Added the Feed and Friends models

Comment: `Friends` does not have a foreign key or many to many with Feed, so Feed should not have a `friends_set` to prefetch. You can prefetch something like `user_info__follows`. Can you include your UserInfo model?

Comment: I didn't notice. Thank you so much. Added UserInfo mode. Can you help me to get an easy way to find if they are friends or not?